# ICMP "echo request" handling on routers running Cisco IOS-XR

Tags: icmp, cisco-ios-xr

I am aware that `ICMP "echo request"` messages addressed to router are handled in process switching in case or routers running IOS. However, what about Cisco ASR9K routers running IOS-XR? Is the handling of `ICMP "echo request"` messages exactly like in software-routers running IOS?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

On ASR9k running IOS-XR ICMP packets destined to the router are handled by LTPS (Local Packet Transport System). I believe that under normal circumstances the entire processing of such packet is done on ingress linecard CPU.

Once the NP on ingress LC detects the packet is for-us, it hands it over to LTPS. LTPS will perform policing, conforming packets are then passed either to LC CPU or RP.

The counters for different kinds of traffic for particular LC can be checked with following command:

```
RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:ASR9006#show lpts pifib hardware police location 0/1/CPU0
Tue May 19 11:03:19.188 UTC
-------------------------------------------------------------
                Node 0/1/CPU0:
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Burst = 100ms for all flow types 
-------------------------------------------------------------
FlowType               Policer Type    Cur. Rate  Def. Rate  Accepted             Dropped              TOS Value 
---------------------- ------- ------- ---------- ---------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------
unconfigured-default   100     Static  2500       2500       0                    0                    01234567            
L2TPv2-fragment        185     Static  10000      10000      0                    0                    01234567            
Fragment               101     Static  2500       2500       0                    0                    01234567            
OSPF-mc-known          102     Static  2000       2000       356486               0                    01234567            
OSPF-mc-default        103     Static  1500       1500       0                    0                    01234567            
OSPF-uc-known          104     Static  2000       2000       81                   0                    01234567            
OSPF-uc-default        105     Static  1000       1000       0                    0                    01234567            
ISIS-known             143     Static  2000       2000       0                    0                    01234567            
ISIS-default           144     Static  1500       1500       0                    0                    01234567            
BFD-known              150     Static  9600       9600       0                    0                    01234567            
BFD-default            160     Static  45340      9600       0                    0                    01234567            
BFD-MP-known           178     Static  11520      11520      0                    0                    01234567            
BFD-MP-0               179     Static  128        128        0                    0                    01234567            
BFD-BLB-known          183     Static  11520      11520      0                    0                    01234567            
BFD-BLB-0              184     Static  128        128        0                    0                    01234567            
BFD-SP-0               182     Static  512        512        0                    0                    01234567            
BGP-known              106     Static  2500       2500       1424782              0                    01234567            
BGP-cfg-peer           107     Static  2000       2000       8                    0                    01234567            
BGP-default            108     Static  1500       1500       87                   0                    01234567            
PIM-mcast-default      109     Static  2000       2000       0                    0                    01234567            
PIM-mcast-known        176     Static  2000       2000       0                    0                    01234567            
PIM-ucast              110     Static  1500       1500       0                    0                    01234567            
IGMP                   111     Static  3000       3000       0                    0                    01234567            
ICMP-local             112     Static  1500       1500       17                   0                    01234567            
ICMP-app               152     Static  1500       1500       0                    0                    01234567            
ICMP-control           140     Static  1000       1000       0                    0                    01234567            
ICMP-default           153     Static  1500       1500       2                    0                    01234567            
ICMP-app-default       152     Static  1500       1500       0                    0                    01234567            
LDP-TCP-known          113     Static  2500       2500       56736                0                    01234567            
LDP-TCP-cfg-peer       114     Static  2000       2000       0                    0                    01234567            
LDP-TCP-default        115     Static  1500       1500       0                    0                    01234567            
LDP-UDP                116     Static  2000       2000       401486               0                    01234567            
All-routers            117     Static  1000       1000       0                    0                    01234567            
LMP-TCP-known          168     Static  2500       2500       0                    0                    01234567            
LMP-TCP-cfg-peer       169     Static  2000       2000       0                    0                    01234567            
LMP-TCP-default        170     Static  1500       1500       0                    0                    01234567            
LMP-UDP                171     Static  2000       2000       0                    0                    01234567            
RSVP-UDP               118     Static  2000       2000       0                    0                    01234567            
RSVP-default           154     Static  500        500        0                    0                    01234567            
RSVP-known             177     Static  7000       7000       0                    0                    01234567            
IKE                    119     Static  100        100        0                    0                    01234567            
IPSEC-known            120     Static  400        400        0                    0                    01234567            
IPSEC-default          121     Static  100        100        0                    0                    01234567            
MSDP-known             122     Static  300        300        0                    0                    01234567            
MSDP-cfg-peer          123     Static  200        200        0                    0                    01234567            
MSDP-default           124     Static  100        100        0                    0                    01234567            
SNMP                   125     Static  300        300        221047               0                    01234567            
SSH-known              127     Static  300        300        597                  0                    01234567            
SSH-default            128     Static  200        200        218                  0                    01234567            
HTTP-known             129     Static  400        400        0                    0                    01234567            
HTTP-default           130     Static  200        200        0                    0                    01234567            
SHTTP-known            161     Static  400        400        0                    0                    01234567            
IFIB_FT_SHTTP_DEFAULT  162     Static  200        200        0                    0                    01234567            
TELNET-known           131     Static  200        200        0                    0                    01234567            
TELNET-default         132     Static  200        200        0                    0                    01234567            
CSS-known              133     Static  200        200        0                    0                    01234567            
CSS-default            134     Static  200        200        0                    0                    01234567            
RSH-known              135     Static  200        200        0                    0                    01234567            
RSH-default            136     Static  200        200        0                    0                    01234567            
UDP-known              137     Static  2500       2500       0                    0                    01234567            
UDP-listen             138     Static  2500       2500       0                    0                    01234567            
UDP-cfg-peer           155     Static  2500       2500       0                    0                    01234567            
UDP-default            163     Static  3500       3500       2396                 0                    01234567            
TCP-known              156     Static  2500       2500       0                    0                    01234567            
TCP-listen             157     Static  2500       2500       0                    0                    01234567            
TCP-cfg-peer           158     Static  2000       2000       0                    0                    01234567            
TCP-default            164     Static  2000       2000       72                   0                    01234567            
Mcast-known            159     Static  2500       2500       0                    0                    01234567            
Mcast-default          165     Static  2000       2000       0                    0                    01234567            
Raw-listen             166     Static  2500       2500       0                    0                    01234567            
Raw-default            167     Static  2500       2500       0                    0                    01234567            
Ip-Sla                 139     Static  1000       1000       0                    0                    01234567            
EIGRP                  145     Static  1500       1500       0                    0                    01234567            
RIP                    146     Static  1500       1500       0                    0                    01234567            
L2TPv3                 141     Static  400        400        0                    0                    01234567            
PCEP                   142     Static  200        200        0                    0                    01234567            
GRE                    147     Static  10000      10000      0                    0                    01234567            
VRRP                   148     Static  1000       1000       0                    0                    01234567            
HSRP                   149     Static  400        400        0                    0                    01234567            
MPLS-oam               151     Static  250        250        0                    0                    01234567            
L2TPv2-default         172     Static  2000       2000       0                    0                    01234567            
L2TPv2-known           181     Static  2500       2500       0                    0                    01234567            
DNS                    173     Static  2000       2000       0                    0                    01234567            
RADIUS                 174     Static  2000       2000       0                    0                    01234567            
TACACS                 175     Static  2000       2000       0                    0                    01234567            
NTP-default            126     Static  200        200        0                    0                    01234567            
NTP-known              180     Static  200        200        0                    0                    01234567            
AMT                    186     Static  4000       4000       0                    0                    01234567            
MIPv6                  188     Static  0          0          0                    0                    01234567            
SDAC-TCP               187     Static  5000       5000       0                    0                    01234567            
ONEPK                  189     Static  0          0          0                    0                    01234567
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! Do you have some sort of Cisco reference for this, i.e. some sort of day in the life of a packet document?

Comment: Sure, I recommend Cisco Live session BRKARC-2017 - Packet Journey inside ASR9000 available here: https://www.ciscolive.com/online/connect/sessionDetail.ww?SESSION_ID=78451